# What is the difference between Democracy and Ochlocracy

Tags: democracy, government, ochlocracy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which are the symptoms of a decadent Democracy degenerating to Ochlocracy?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/351/which-are-the-symptoms-of-a-decadent-democracy-degenerating-to-ochlocracy)

Democracy is rule by the people, and Ochlocracy is rule by the mob.  Is there a defining point between a democracy and an ochlocracy?

Comment: Not really. That question asks about what are the signs of a democracy turning *into* an ochlocracy, but here we are contrasting two completely different systems.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in connotation and methods of government, I think. Democracy aims to govern peacefully by the people, through civilized means. Mob rule is when "democracy" turns into "the masses brutalize everyone else that gets in their way".